# Sludge in the radiator

Tags: engine, kia

I have a 08 Kia Rio 5. A mechanic recently rebuild the engine, replaced water pump, changed timing belts etc etc, but now it's leaking oil - not just that, I also found sludge in the radiator and loosing oil. The car is drivable, not overheating, shifts smoothly, just the leaking.
What should I do?

Comment: What was the original reason that you took the car to the mechanic?

Answer (score 1):

Take it back to the mechanic who did the work and have him redo everything. Sounds as though there is an internal oil leak which is dumping oil into the coolant system. It could be as simple as a gasket out of place or as bad as a crack somewhere. Whatever the deal is, the mechanic should have caught the issue while putting it back together. Since you paid for the job, you are due the job done right. Make them take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to tell you this, but more than likely the engine is dead.

If I am correct in assuming that the Kia Rio has aluminum heads, I'd go out on a limb and say that the heads are likely warped, and you are leaking oil into the cooling system.

It could be an out of place gasket, but my guess is that it is either a crack somewhere in the water jacket or a warped head.

First, do an oil change. If the oil comes out looking like a frappuchino, you need to get the mechanic to fix it. It is likely his mistake.